# How to Handle Flex grid with selenium web driver?

Tags: apache-flex, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sikuli, flex-mx

How to handle Flex grid with selenium web driver?

Right now I am using sikuli api (image processing) but it is not a good solution. if you have solution for it please give step wise answer which you have tested.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to automate a flex application you need to add instrumentation features to your compiled SWF. This can usually be done using a loader application, that applies the instrumentation, or you compile this in to the application you are intending to automate. The webdriver then communicates with these automation-stubs and is able to take full control of the application.

Here is a description of the general Automation concepts:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ec5.html
This article should explain the actual steps needed for Selenium2 with Webdriver:
http://www.blackpepper.co.uk/driving-a-flex-application-via-selenium-2-webdriver/

Comment: nice explanation for the same is here : 
http://edu.yoursfriends.com/38/how-to-handle-flex-in-selenium-web-driver?show=39#a39

Answer (score 0):

Handling flex grid in selenium is not a simple task, After some research, this task has been done successfully , Although selenium is providing SeleniumFlexAPI API by which you can perform actions in flex grid.

These are the steps which we need to follow:

1. you have to download selenium flex API .
2. you will get a SeleniumFlexAPI.swc file here.

   a.  you need to put this file in your flex application (In the repository or in your project libs folder).

   b. you need to add lib path in flex compiler like this and compile the code

   ```
     -include-libraries "libs\SeleniumFlexAPI.swc"
   ```

[Source with Example](http://asktofolks.com/38/how-to-handle-flex-in-selenium-web-driver)