# I'm unable to click on a element with it's ID using Selenium. There's "flex" written inside a rounded rectangle when I inspect element. Any solutions?

Tags: java, selenium, flexbox, calendar, click

I'm trying to click on an element using selenium and make a calender pop up.
I think that the "flex thingy" has something to do with this.

I'm trying to click on the "Date of Travel" button to make the calender pop up on this website: https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companion/

Here's my code

`driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companion/");`
`driver.findElement(By.id("form-field-travel_comp_date")).click();`

For some reason, the calendar does not pop up.

I'm very new to this and I apologize if this sounds stupid. I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30206106/7598774) - Refer this if it helps

Comment: Hey. I found a fix. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Do you mind sharing your fix in the form of an answer so that it will be useful for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this has nothing to do with flex. I had to scroll a bit lower for the calender to pop up. The below code sorted things.

```
driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companion/");   
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)");
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("form-field-travel_comp_date")).click();
```